# Weird call of Class_Terminate

Tags: vba, scripting, powerpoint

I really don't know why this is happening:

This hier is a little presentation wrapper:

```
' Class PPTGenPresentation

Private m_Presentation As Presentation

Public Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_Presentation = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub Class_Terminate()
    If Not m_Presentation Is Nothing Then
        m_Presentation.Close
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Initialize(ByVal presentationPath As String)
    On Error GoTo Error

    Set m_Presentation = Presentations.Open(presentationPath, , , msoFalse)

    Exit Sub
Error:
    MsgBox ("Could not open " & presentationPath)
End Sub


Public Property Get Instance() As Presentation
    ' After this line Class_Terminate() gets called somehow ..
    Instance = m_Presentation
End Property
```

After I opened the ppt I want to access the actual presentation by accessing the property:

```
For Each filePath In filePaths
    Set safePresentation = New PPTGenPresentation
    safePresentation.Initialize (filePath)

    Dim tmp As Presentation
    Set tmp = savePresentation.Instance

    For Each oSlide In tmp.Slides
        Set oShape = oSlide.Shapes(1)

        If oShape.HasTextFrame Then
            If oShape.TextFrame.HasText Then
                MsgBox oShape.TextFrame                    
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

But after accessing the property `Instance`, somehow `Class_terminate` gets called.

I have no idea why ths is happening. Could somebody explain to me what the problem is?

Comment: What is the rest of the code? Are you sure you aren't leaving the scope of `safePresentation` immediately after the `set tmp` line?

Comment: Hi! Well, no.. I edited the code a little. After accessing the instance another For Each loop iterates through the slied of the actual presentation instance.

Comment: I am assuming this class is called `PPTGenPresentation` as well?

Comment: No, the `Instance` property is a `Presentation` type.

Comment: I mean the wrapper class you posted.

Comment: Sorry my bad! Yes, the wrapper class is `PPTGenPresentation`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43137/discussion-between-enderland-and-stefan-falk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added comments to your code.

Basically, when you use `set=new` to overwrite an object (as happens in each subsequent iteration through your For Each loop) the previous object has either one of two situations from a theoretical standpoint:

1. The reference is lost but the object exists and now creates a memory leak
2. The object is automatically cleaned up and destroyed when the reference is gone

VBA automatically causes the second to be true. When you use "New" again, the first presentation no longer will have any way to refer to it, and so it is cleaned up and destroyed. This calls `Class_Terminate`

Just a note, in other languages without this sort of code you have now would start causing memory leaks (such as C++).

```
For Each filePath In filePaths
    'Each subsequent iteration the following basically happens:
    'when you set the presentation to a new one, you are effectively
    'ending the previous version. So for example, the following *basically* happens:

    ' if not safePresentation is nothing then set safePresentation=nothing 

    Set safePresentation = New PPTGenPresentation
    safePresentation.Initialize (filePath)

    Dim tmp As Presentation
    Set tmp = savePresentation.Instance

    For Each oSlide In tmp.Slides
        Set oShape = oSlide.Shapes(1)

    Next
Next
```

To solve this, move `Set safePresentation = New PPTGenPresentation` above your `For Each` loop.

Comment: But shouldn't the object be valid inside the outer loop? It was my intention that `Class_Terminate` gets called after the object leaves the scope such that the presentations gets closed for sure in this case. What if I wanted to access `safePresentation` after the inner loop?

Comment: @StefanFalk what line, specifically, does the presentation get closed on in your For-Each loop when you walk through it with the debugger?

Comment: As I access the property `Instance`. I'll add it to my question. **edit:** I added a comment

Answer (score 1):

It gets called as you have a syntax error in your code and I suspect that you have `On Error Resume Next` in the calling code.

```
Public Property Get Instance() As Presentation
    ' After this line Class_Terminate() gets called somehow ..
    Instance = m_Presentation
End Property
```

Generates an error, which is suppressed by the resume next, try:

```
Public Property Get Instance() As Presentation
    ' After this line Class_Terminate() gets called somehow ..
    Set Instance = m_Presentation
End Property
```

You'd be much better off not suppressing errors, and certainly not when testing